# Switching to GNU/linux

Tags: linux, installation, desktop

I've been using linux at university for quite a while, and it seems much more customisable and better for coding.

So I want to switch to linux from windows 7 at home.

What branch of linux should I use? I'm an emacs user if that gives any insight.

Which desktop enviroment should I use? At uni we use KDE, but it's too graphical, often I just click on stuff instead of using the terminal. I want one where it encourages me to use terminal more.

and the biggest question, how do I install it all? Should I put everything on external hard drive and wipe my computer completley?

I primarily program in Java and python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you first try using Linux off Live CD/DVD.  Linux Mint, Ubuntu, etc.

Just download and burn .iso onto blank media and boot your computer off of it.  Just play around, check various desktop environments, see if all your hardware work with the specific Linux distribution.  This step is very useful to decide which distribution you actually want to install onto your computer, especially the latter since, while it has been improving, the biggest obstacle you may face in configuring your computer to run on Linux is often hardware incompatibility.  Just make sure everything that you need to work actually works.

If you have no issues wiping out Windows, Linux installation is pretty straightforward these days.  It even takes less time in general than re-installing Windows.  I would browse the web for an installation note for your specific computer model to see if anyone has already successfully done so, so that you can just follow.  That saves a lot of time.

I use Debian (Wheezy now) and KDE.  It's very easy to install and switch desktop environments after installing Linux though, so that shouldn't be any concern.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a virtual machine using VMWare or Virtual Box.  As far as the distribution goes, Linux Mint and Ubuntu are pretty user-friendly for first time installations.  And for the desktop environment, I suggest XFCE.

A few Google searches will do you good.  I think a virtual environment will be much more easier to manage than partitioning a hard-drive.

Comment: You can download many Linux distribution VMs from the VMWare site and run them using VMWare Player. I suggest taking a look for yourself, most people are biased towards their own distributions.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE This is true, but I figured he was focused on getting one up and running and going from there.

Comment: You can get most distributions in one form or another as a bootable CD. Knoppix might be a start, it's up and running in no time, and has the option of installing it to hard drive, replicating the bootable CD to your system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the installation step, if you use Windows 7, you may want to make a full backup of your hdd - so if things go wrong you will be safe and able to recover. 
I was in somewhat similar situation recently - figuring out which linux distro to use. Previously I had luck with [ScientificLinux](https://www.scientificlinux.org/news/sl63), but this time it didn't like my laptop hardware for some reason - after wake-up wireless network card was getting stuck and wasnt picking any signal. I didn't want to recompile kernel etc., so I installed [Ubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/), but the Gnome 3 was a show stopper - I had to roll back to Gnome 2, but later I tried and liked a lot [XFCE](http://xfce.org/) desktop - which I use right now on my workstation and laptop.
Java, Python and emacs probably work well with any linux distribution out of the box, so it is up to you which one to choose after all. Good luck!

Sorry, forgot to mention - all contemporary Linux distributions are able to install a dual boot feature - so you can keep your Windows 7 setup along with Linux (if you have enough of free space), moreover Windows partition will be accessible from Linux which is handy sometimes.